# Monitor file access, according to pid

Tags: terminal, file

I was wondering how can I use `lsof` to run in streaming mode, so it will print all files access (RWX) from a specific process (pid).

Also, maybe there's a way to use `lsof` to catch only files that were downloaded from remote server ?

Thanks !

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to understand which files are created by a specific process in a certain period of time. in my experiment, I'd like to start the monitor, then tell the process to run some scenario, and observe the files that were created.

Comment: Sounds like `fs_usage` with a specific pid is a more appropriate command for your use case